# Is there a way to change the tel: and mailTo: links at the Contacts page using aura lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, dom, lightning-web-security, lightning-locker

I am trying to change the `tel:` and `mailTo:` links from the Salesforce contact page to some other behavior with `onClick` using `aura` lightning component. The expected behavior might be click on the phone link and the item from the utility bar will be opened.

Currently, the default behavior for `mailTo` will open up the email application like Mail from Mac. The default behavior for `tel` opens up the Facetime. However, we want to have different behavior when users click on those links.

I think DOM manipulation with script is achievable, but we would like to do it with aura lightning component.

The links are highlighted in the attached image

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Telephone and email links are mostly controlled by the operating system, not the code in a page. For example, changing the default email client in a computer's operating system will change which app opens when you click on an email link. There are a few special exceptions in Salesforce, such as using [Gmail](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.google_gmail_activate.htm&type=5) or enabling [Salesforce Dialer](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.voice_impl_overview.htm&type=5), but these solutions all require that some operating system configuration is set up on each computer.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't clear on the question. What I meant was to not use `tel:` but to have an `onClick` on that link that does something else, for example, clicking on the phone number link opens up an item from the utility bar.